# Fatal error: require_once() with module .install file, drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I get the following error after reinstalling my site on localhost.

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sites/all/modules/custom/redirect/redirect.install'
```

The .install file DOES exist, and is below:

```
 1 <?php
 2 /**
 3  * @file
 4  * 
 5  */
 6 
 7 /**
 8  * Implementation of hook_install().
 9  */
 10 function redirect_install() {
 11 
 12 }
 13 
 14 /**
 15  * Implementation of hook_uninstall().
 16  */
 17 function redirect_uninstall() {
 18   variable_del('desktop_site_home');
 19   variable_del('mobile_site_home');
 20 }
```

The module has no require or include statements at all.

Does anyone have any idea whatsoever what might be going wrong here?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Could it be that XAMPP doesn't have permissions to read the file? The error doesn't specifically say that the file doesn't exist, just that it failed to open it

Answer (score 2):

You have a permissions and/or a file ownership problem.

Fix them quickly. This is my technique:

cd to the module's dir and:

chmod 775 *.install

Optionally, ls -la and see if there is a dominant owner of the files inside the Drupal docroot. Say you have some files owned by www-data in the group www-data.

If so, that's probably the user that your web server is running as. So...

chown www-data:www-data [filename]

hope that helps

joe